# Maximum mid-band gain of s.s. model MOSFET amplifier?

Tags: mosfet, amplifier, gain, nmos, cascode

**Schematics**

I need to find the maximum possible gain for this NMOS cascode circuit.

[image]

Here is the s.s. model:

[image]

**Work**

I used nodal-matrix analysis (basis is KCL) to find the gain (\$A_v\$):

$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{1}{r_{o1}}+\frac{1}{r_{o2}} & -\frac{1}{r_{o2}} \\
    -\frac{1}{r_{o2}} & \frac{1}{r_{o2}}+\frac{1}{(R_{L1}\,||\,50)} \\
    \end{bmatrix}
\cdot
    \begin{bmatrix}
    V_A \\
    V_B \\
    \end{bmatrix}
=
    \begin{bmatrix}
    -gm1\cdot V_{in} - gm2\cdot V_A \\
    gm2\cdot V_A \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
    \Longrightarrow
    \begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{1}{r_{o1}}+\frac{1}{r_{o2}}+gm2 & -\frac{1}{r_{o2}} \\
    -\frac{1}{r_{o2}}-gm2 & \frac{1}{r_{o2}}+\frac{1}{(R_{L1}\,||\,50)} \\
    \end{bmatrix}
\cdot
    \begin{bmatrix}
    V_A \\
    V_B \\
    \end{bmatrix}
=
    \begin{bmatrix}
    -gm1\cdot V_{in} \\
    0 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
\Longrightarrow V_A = D/C,\quad V_B = -\frac{v_{in}\cdot (r_{o1}\cdot gm1)\cdot (r_{o2}\cdot gm2 + 1)\cdot (R_{L1}\,||\,50)}{r_{o1}\cdot r_{o2}\cdot gm2+r_{o1}+r_{o2}+(R_{L1}\,||\,50)}
$$

$$
V_B = V_{out} = -\frac{v_{in}\cdot (r_{o1}\cdot gm1)\cdot (r_{o2}\cdot gm2 + 1)\cdot (R_{L1}\,||\,50)}{r_{o1}\cdot r_{o2}\cdot gm2+r_{o1}+r_{o2}+(R_{L1}\,||\,50)}
$$

$$
\Longrightarrow \frac{V_{out}}{V_{in}} = A_v = -\frac{(r_{o1}\cdot gm1)\cdot (r_{o2}\cdot gm2 + 1)\cdot (R_{L1}\,||\,50)}{r_{o1}\cdot r_{o2}\cdot gm2+r_{o1}+r_{o2}+(R_{L1}\,||\,50)}
$$

This is the part where I am stuck; I was told that increasing \$gm\$ and \$R_L\$ will reveal the maximum gain but I don't really understand what that entails. Thus far, my interpretation of "increasing \$gm\$ and \$R_L\$" has been:

$$
\lim\limits_{(gm1,gm2,R_{L1}) \to (\infty,\infty, \infty)} A_v
$$

However, I've had trouble finding a reliable/straight-forward method for calculating these simultaneous/multi-variable limits, so I assumed that my interpretation was incorrect. For instance, when I [apply this interpretation using Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit%20(r,x,y)%20-%3E%20(inf,inf,inf)%20of%20(-((a*x)*(b*y%20%2B%201)*((r*50)%2F(r%2B50)))%2F(a*b*y%20%2B%20a%20%2B%20b%20%2B%20((r*50)%2F(r%2B50))))) (the only calculator I could find to compute these types of limits), I receive the following output:

*(limit does not exist, is path dependent, or cannot be determined)*

If you can provide a better interpretation, please enlighten me.

**Remarks**

- I'd like to know the max-gain but I am more interested in being taught a correct/straight-forward method that is applicable to any similar problem.
- Although this is most likely a question of mathematical understanding, it belongs here b.c. many EE's might have already solved this problem or they might bring enough insight about the circuit (NMOS cascode is recognizable/typical) to derive a solution (or provide the final answer at-least).

Comment: Basically it will be zero because Q2's gate is tied to ground.

Comment: @Andyaka I don't see how you're correct since, for any reasonable insertion of values, my A_v eq returns a non-zero answer. It seems to tend towards -infinity, as R_L1 and gm's increase.

Comment: @Andyaka And on a fundamental level, a MOSFET's gate being tied to ground doesn't imply that it's output is 0. If the gate and the source were tied to ground (V_GS = V_G - V_S = 0) then the s.s. dep. current source would be 0 & output would be 0. But that isn't the case here.

Comment: I never said your output would be zero; I was answering your title question and saying the gain would be zero. But please sit and wait for that answer.

Comment: @Andyaka I doubt it will receive an answer ),;